# How to rotate text in user coordinate system?

Tags: graphics, annotation

Applying `Rotate` to text rotates it relative to the Cartesian page coordinates. I want it rotated relative to the current user coordinate system. As a simple illustration (of a more general problem), consider the following manipulation. When the `AspectRatio` is `1`, all is good; but otherwise not. (I've included a plot for an apect ratio of 1/2, to illustrate.) How can I keep the text on the line?

```
Manipulate[With[{f = x |-> (x + 0.4)^2, x0 = 1, x1 = 2},
  Module[{y0 = f[x0], y1 = f[x1]},
   Graphics[{
     Line[{{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}}],
     Text[
      Rotate["test", ArcTan[1, (y1 - y0)/(x1 - x0)]], {(x0 + x1)/2, (y0 + y1)/2}, {0, -2}]
     },
    PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 6}},
    Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> a,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]],
 {{a, 1}, 1/2, 1}]
```

[image: outcome for aspect ratio of 1/2]

More generally, it seems that Mathematica has much to learn from TikZ about making annotation easy for users.

Comment: try `Rotate[Text["test", {(x0 + x1)/2, (y0 + y1)/2}, {0, -2}],  ArcTan[1, (y1 - y0)/(x1 - x0)]]` or `Text[Rotate["test",  ArcTan[1, a (y1 - y0)/(x1 - x0)]], {(x0 + x1)/2, (y0 + y1)/
   2}, {0, -2 a}]`?

Comment: @kglr You are correct that when I set the aspect ratio I can use it to scale the angle, but I am seeking a general solution for rotation in "user coordinates". (Like in PostScript.) Or alternatively, a way to say "place this text near the end of this line, aligned with the line". (Like in TikZ.)

Comment: In other words : we shouldn't have to inject the AspectRatio in the code that contains the graphic primitives. No ?

Comment: @andre314 Right!

Comment: @kglr I forgot to add: if you create the text and then rotate it, it distorts. That's why I show rotating it and then placing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Manipulate[With[{f = Function[x, (x + 0.4)^2], x0 = 1, x1 = 2}, 
   Module[{y0 = f[x0], y1 = f[x1]}, 
    Graphics[{Line[{{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}}], 
      Text[Rotate["test", ArcTan[x1 - x0, a*(y1 - y0)]], 
       {(x0 + x1)/2, (y0 + y1)/2}, {0, -2*a}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 6}}, Axes -> True, 
     AspectRatio -> a, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]], 
  {{a, 1}, 1/2, 1}]
```

The two argument form of *ArcTan* handles getting the rotation angle into the correct quadrant.

The AspectRatio effectively scales the *y* coordinate. Therefore, another correction is needed in the *ArcTan* function evocation. For similar reasons I also scaled the offset parameter.

Of course, I may have missed something.

Comment: See my comments to @kglr.

Comment: OK, I missed something. Namely, it was answered in the comments.